# How to retain links between assets when merging two projects into one?

Tags: unity, materials

We have a common Model library where different models/textures are stored. We use this library for our new project. Here is the scenario:
Two individuals started separate projects and are now merging them into one. Both of them added models from the common library. However, when they merge their work into a third project by importing each other's package (model/material package), some models lose their materials and appear pink, even though the materials are present and not lost. I tried to identify the problem and found a warning message when importing the same model:

```
File exists in the project, but with a new different GUID. Will override existing asset...
```

I discovered that Unity operates models based on GUIDs. So, if two different workspaces added the same material and you attempt to merge them into a single project, only the latest GUID will remain, causing your model to lose the material reference. Is there any available way to recover the material? Or i have to change the workflow, which is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you [enable asset metadata](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/AssetMetadata.html).

Every asset in a Unity project is accompanied by a corresponding file of the same name with the additional extension `.meta`.

When you exchange assets between projects, copy their corresponding meta-files with them. The meta-file contains the GUID of the asset file of the same name. So when you copy both the meta-file and the asset into the project, then the asset will get the GUID from the meta-file instead of a newly generated one.

The meta-file also contains the import settings, which can also be crucial for certain asset types.

Comment: Do you mean i should manually copy the models with meta files instead the pacakge?

Comment: @MuhammadFaizanKhan What type of "package" exactly are you talking about?

Comment: unity package..

Comment: @MuhammadFaizanKhan There are multiple kinds of unity packages. Are you talking about asset packs? Or packages installed via the package manager? (by the way, neither is a recommended way to collaborate in a development team. You should really use a version control software like Git or Plastic)

Comment: I believe the original projects will be pointing at the same asset on disk post-merge, so the question becomes "Which of the 2 meta files do you keep"?

Comment: @Philipp we create custom package to merge things.